# How to hook up NSWindowDelegate in macOS game template

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is a "how-to" for related question:
[cocoa windowDidEnterFullScreen not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280025/cocoa-windowdidenterfullscreen-not-being-called?rq=1)

Using the Xcode (9.1) macOS "game" template -

I would like to create a simple `NSWindowDelegate` using the AppDelegate class. However I can't seem to connect the given `NSWindow` outlet to anything.

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window; // won't connect

@end
```

I assume I'm supposed to connect to a "Window" within the storyboard. This is what happens when I try to connect - the inspector does not show up.

[image]

What am I missing here?

*Note: I'm just playing around so I don't care if AppDelegate is the right place or not, I just want something to work.*

**EDIT 1**

Using suggestion from answer, I've tried connecting the 'TestFullscreen' window to the AppDelegate object, but it still won't connect, either from the AppDelegate inspector or the property declaration in the code.

[image]

Comment: If you are just using AppDelegate to write everything, you don't need NSWindowController.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `Delegate` object and that is what should hook up to your window.

[image]

[image]

It looks like you are currently attempting to connect the window to itself. Also it doesn't appear you have a view for the window either, so you'll need to add that for the window content.

Comment: Thanks, but still won't connect to my delegate. Is there a chance I've mixed up the WindowController with the Window itself?

Comment: @Justicle: I mistakenly posted what would normally be done for nibs, and xibs. Basically with storyboards you'll hook your WindowController up to a ViewController. This example should shed some light on how it's done: https://github.com/stonehouse/T-Minus

Comment: Looked at the project - Not sure how that will help? - I want to respond to NSWindow messages, not NSWindowController messages.

Comment: @Justicle: Storyboards don't work the same way as a nib or xib does, so the delegate connections don't hook directly to a window. Generally you'd have a WindowController > Window > First Responder > Then Storyboard Entry Point. Personally I don't like using storyboards on macOS because of the convoluted segue necessity and all that, however, creating a new basic storyboard app should show you how the connections are made in a typical project. BTW - I think there's a bug in Xcode, maybe you can confirm? - control-c (copy) on "window" underneath Window Controller it crashes (at least for me).

Comment: Also Did you try connecting the "TestFullScreen" window underneath the Window Controller over to the View Controller View? That should work.

Comment: cmd-c works for me, cmd-v crashes Xcode pretty hard.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to simply create non-Workspace project.

Editing the XIB allows you to connect the Window delegate outlet to the AppDelegate, after it has NSWindowDelegate protocol specified.